# How to convert ASCII integers back to char within a loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ascii, chr, ord

I'm trying to convert multiple ASCII ints back to char and have it as a single string. I know how to do it one by one but I can't think of how to do it in a loop. This is the code I have to grab all the ascii ints in my ascii_message variable:

```
for c in ascii_message: 
    ascii_int = ord(c)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `list(map(chr, ascii_ints))` without a loop, btw, `ord` is for converting to ordinals and `chr` is for converting back to characters.

Comment: or w/a list comp.
[ord(c) for c in ascii_message]

Comment: @abccd, when I try that I get TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm using 2.7.14.

Comment: @Ken What is your `ascii_ints`? If it’s just one `int`, `chr(ascii_int)` is what you need. I assumed you were wanting to convert a list of ordinals.

Comment: @abccd it's multiple ints, 16 to be exact

Comment: Do you want the result to be a single string, or a list of 1 char strings?

Comment: @PM2Ring, I want the result to be a single string.

Comment: Could you `print(ascii_ints)` and show the exact output?

Comment: @abccd `48 98 49 48 49 49 48 48 48 49 48 49 48 49 48 48`

Comment: Which it isn’t a `list` nor any iterable, I suppose they are individual ints that got printed when they were being iterated. `print(type(ascii_ints))` will most likely print `int`, just use `chr(ascii_int)` and I’ll think you’ll get what you want.

Answer (score 5):

An efficient way to do this in Python 2 is to load the list into a `bytearray` object & then convert that to a string. Like this:

```
ascii_message = [
    83, 111, 109, 101, 32, 65, 83, 67, 
    73, 73, 32, 116, 101, 120, 116, 46,
]

a = bytearray(ascii_message)
s = str(a)
print s
```

**output**

```
Some ASCII text.
```

Here's a variation that works correctly in both Python 2 & 3.

```
a = bytearray(ascii_message)
s = a.decode('ASCII')
```

However, in Python 3, it'd be more usual to use an immutable `bytes` object rather than a mutable `bytearray`.

```
a = bytes(ascii_message)
s = a.decode('ASCII')
```

---

The reverse procedure can also be done efficiently with a `bytearray` in both Python 2 and 3.

```
s = 'Some ASCII text.'
a = list(bytearray(s.encode('ASCII')))
print(a)
```

**output**

```
[83, 111, 109, 101, 32, 65, 83, 67, 73, 73, 32, 116, 101, 120, 116, 46]
```

---

If your "list of numbers" is actually a string, you can convert it to a proper list of integers like this.

```
numbers = '48 98 49 48 49 49 48 48 48 49 48 49 48 49 48 48'
ascii_message = [int(u) for u in numbers.split()]
print(ascii_message)

a = bytearray(ascii_message)
s = a.decode('ASCII')
print(s)
```

**output**

```
[48, 98, 49, 48, 49, 49, 48, 48, 48, 49, 48, 49, 48, 49, 48, 48]
0b10110001010100
```

That looks the binary representation of a 14 bit number. So I guess there are further steps to solving this puzzle. Good luck!